# Can pylearn2 and Theano run on AMD GPU based platform?

Tags: cuda, scikit-learn, opencl, neural-network, theano

I'd like to use pylearn2, theano and scikit-neuralnetwork to build neural network models. But my friend told me that all this module can only run on NVIDIA GPU based platform (because they would import the pycuda module). But I only have an AMD GPU(R9 270,and an AMD FX-8300 CPU),and I wish to take advantage of AMD GPU to speed up computing. Can I use all of the modules metioned above? Or is there any substitutes I can use to build neural network models ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Theano only supports nvidia GPUs. There is a partial implementation of an OpenCL backend that would support AMD GPUs but it is incomplete and unsupported.

scikit-neuralnetwork builds on PyLearn2 and PyLearn2 builds on Theano so none of those packages can operate on AMD GPUs.

Torch appears to already have some [OpenCL support](https://github.com/torch/torch7/wiki/Cheatsheet#opencl). Caffe's OpenCL support appears to be [under development](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/2195).

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. It is a little pitty. How about DeepCL? How about it's performance compared with the above mentioned packages? And convnetjs, which doesn't seems to rely on GPU. C++ or js binding is ok as well.

Comment: Theano runs fine on CPU if that's okay with you. I don't have enough experience with the other packages to comment on them.